# Grab user_id inside a function

Tags: users

I want to create one simple function to grab a user's id depending on which page we're on in WP.

```
function wp_user_id( $user ) {  

        if ( is_page_template( 'page-recipes.php' ) ) {     
            $user = get_current_user_id();          
         elseif( is_singular() ) {
            $user = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
        } else {
            $user = $user;
        }

        return $user;   

    }
```

When I'm on a singular page and only use wp_user_id() in my code, I get an error saying `Missing argument 1 for wp_user_id()` while I want it to get `$user = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of your function accepting the $user argument?

Comment: Inside other functions, I've to constantly use the `if statement` (`is_page_template` and `is_singular`) to get the right `$user(id)`.To save code, I simply wanted to create a function and then simply call `$user = wp_user_id();` But I also want to have an option that I can tweak the `user ID`. Therefore the extra  `$user = $user;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires an input argument `$user` in order to work.

If you simply call `wp_user_id()` without any argument it will return an error.

The solution is giving `$user` a default value, making the argument optional.

```
function wp_user_id( $user = NULL ) { // Give $user a default value of NULL

    if ( empty($user) ) { // check if $user has a non-empty value
        if ( is_page_template( 'page-recipes.php' ) ) {
            $user = get_current_user_id();
        } else if ( is_singular() ) {
            $user = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
        }
    }

    return $user;

}
```

EDIT: I just realised your `$user` argument is actually pointless in your example function. You could remove it entirely.

```
function wp_user_id() {

    if ( is_page_template( 'page-recipes.php' ) ) {
        $user = get_current_user_id();
    } else if ( is_singular() ) {
        $user = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
    }

    if ( isset($user) ) { // check if $user is set
        return $user;
    }

}
```